# Ruby Install through RVM fails with dependecies error

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, installation, rvm

I am trying to install ruby on my machine using rvm. I have installed rvm. When i use 
    $ rvm requirements

it gives the following error.

```
tahir@tahir:~$ rvm requirements
Installing requirements for ubuntu, might require sudo password.
[sudo] password for suhail: 
Ign http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal InRelease
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security InRelease
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal InRelease
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg
Ign http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates InRelease
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release.gpg
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal Release
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release
Ign http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports InRelease
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal/main Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Sources
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal/main i386 Packages
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Sources
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release.gpg
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Sources
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports Release.gpg
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports Release
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Sources
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Sources
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main i386 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Translation-en
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Translation-en_US
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Sources
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Sources
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Sources
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Sources
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main i386 Packages
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main Sources
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Sources
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Sources
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Sources
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main i386 Packages
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Translation-en
Ign http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://pk.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Translation-en_US
Reading package lists...
Installing required packages: gawk, g++, libreadline6-dev, zlib1g-dev, libssl-dev, libyaml-dev, libsqlite3-dev, sqlite3, libxml2-dev, libxslt1-dev, autoconf, libgdbm-dev, libncurses5-dev, automake, libtool, bison, libffi-dev..................
Error running 'requirements_debian_libs_install gawk g++ libreadline6-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev autoconf libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison libffi-dev',
please read /home/suhail/.rvm/log/1370081458_package_install_gawk_g++_libreadline6-dev_zlib1g-dev_libssl-dev_libyaml-dev_libsqlite3-dev_sqlite3_libxml2-dev_libxslt1-dev_autoconf_libgdbm-dev_libncurses5-dev_automake_libtool_bison_libffi-dev.log
```

i have tried to remove the requirements_debian_libs_install with sudo apt-get install but it still fails

I have also tried to use 
    $ sudo apt-get -f install 
but it still breaks (saying dependencies are unmet) and does not install.

What should be done to fix the error?

Comment: Please eplain what you mean by _still breaks and does not install_. And what's inside that log file?

Comment: Its says that dependencies are unmet.

Comment: What version of rvm are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you have installed rvm through apt-get

If so, remove it and reinstall through the guide at https://rvm.io/rvm/install This command will install rvm with ruby (stable)

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

If you need to, you can specify what version of ruby or just install whatever version you want afterwards. rvm use

```
rvm use 1.9.3
```

Also, I would recommend installing it per user, not globally. Unless you have any particular need to have it installed for every user.